# How to collect specific information in a file

Tags: linux, unix, sed, awk

I have the need for different hardware information. such as serial numbers, capabilities, among many others, and for that, I found the `hwinfo`, but it gets information far beyond what I need.

For example:

```
18: IDE 200.0: 10600 Disk
[Created at block.245] 
Unique ID: WZeP.yFECJK3_8V4
Parent ID: w7Y8.7HLn7TSO9I7
SysFS ID: / class / block / sdb
SysFS BusID: 2: 0: 0: 0
SysFS Device Link:/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata3/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0
Hardware Class: disk
Model: "KINGSTON SV300S3"
Vendor: "KINGSTON"
Device: "SV300S3"
Revision: "BBF0"
Serial ID "50026B77470B5AC3"
Driver: "ahci", "sd"
Driver Modules "ahci"
Device File: / dev / sdb
Device Files: / dev / sdb, / dev / disk / by-id / ata KINGSTON_SV300S37A120G_50026B77470B5AC3, / dev / disk / by-id / WWN-0x50026b77470b5ac3
Device Number: block 8: 16-8: 31
BIOS id: 0x81
Geometry (Logical): CHS 14593/255/63
Size: 234441648 sectors 512 bytes
Capacity: 111 GB (120,034,123,776 bytes)
Config Status: config = new, avail = yes, need = no, active = unknown
Attached to: # 13 (controller SATA)
```

I needed to get this information block the `Unique ID`,`Hardware class` , `model`,`Serial ID`, `Device File` among others ..

But the problem does not stop there, because besides disk information, need cpu, memory, etc ..
How could I be selecting this information and saving it to a text file? Doing some research, I found the `SED` and `AWK`, but I believe that implementing a caputra information with these two programs would be laborious, or would be the correct path?

Comment: Depends on what you want for your output.  And, how many input files (or outputs of commands) you need to collect.
It could be really easy with sed/awk and maybe one or two lines of bash, or you could do something really easily in any of the many scripting languages out there (Perl, Python, Ruby, Node.js, etc.).  But, all depends on your needs... I'd start with a bash script containing sed and/or awk commands as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While sed and awk are powerful, for the requirements that you have specified so far, you only need the much simpler `grep`:

```
$ hwinfo | grep -E 'Unique ID|Hardware class|model|Serial ID|Device File:'
Unique ID: WZeP.yFECJK3_8V4
Serial ID "50026B77470B5AC3"
Device File: / dev / sdb
```

(The above output was generated using the hwinfo output as shown in the question.)

Comment: But there is the possibility of more than one block of information when, for example, ask `hwinfo --partition` where there is multiple partitions. So how to separate multiple instances of `Unique ID` or `Hardware class`?

Comment: @MatheusRagoso, (first, @John1024's answer is perfect, and in no way am I pointing at my answer, but) to answer your question about how to separate different instances, can I suggest you look at using tools like `sed` and `awk`, which give you more power to define rules for specific blocks of text... grep is awesome, but combine it with or reach for other tools when you need more power.

Answer (score 0):

Try starting with a bash/shell script that uses sed with suppression and printing.

For example, (and I'm not familiar with hwinfo, but I'm assuming it's a command that outputs to stdout):

```
hwinfo | sed -n '/^Unique ID.*/p; /^Hardware class.*/p;'
```

This will give you just the lines for "Unique ID" and "Hardware class".

To capture to a file and make this command more legible, simply use `>` to output to file, and you can break lines with `\`:

So, this:

```
hwinfo | sed -n '/^Unique ID.*/p; /^Hardware class.*/p;' > myoutputfile.txt
```

Can be turned into a multi-line command, that can capture more parameters, like this:

```
hwinfo | sed -n '/^Unique ID.*/p;'\
'/^Hardware class.*/p;'\
 > myoutputfile.txt # space at beginning of this line is important.
```